# Encoding a time series with varying time differences as an image

Tags: time-series, markov-process, signal-processing

There are methods to encode a time series into an 'image' i.e a matrix of scalar values. Some methods include [recurrence plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot#:%7E:text=In%20descriptive%20statistics%20and%20chaos,it%20is%20a%20graph%20of), [gramian angular field](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/WS/AAAIW15/paper/viewFile/10179/10251) and [markov transition field](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07273.pdf). Most methods assume some correlation / similarity between past values and future values for discernible patterns in the image.

I have only seen these image encoding methods applied to time series with constant time difference between samples e.g. $\Delta t = $ 1 second, 1 minute, 1 day.

My question is, is it possible to apply these methods to time series that have varying time difference between samples? For example, if we have a process sampled at times 18:52:07, 18:53:18, 18:53:19, 19:05:04 etc. the difference between sampled times varies.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, since I haven't tried this myself: CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks) were originally designed for image processing and are now showing promise with time series problems as well. They might (based on my limited understanding of how they apply to time series) be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Beyond approaches inspired by image processing though, Facebook Prophet time series API can handle time series with unequal time steps.